# How can I swap the element at index0 of an ArrayList with another element if the index of that element is found through a private method? (Java)

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, private-methods

I'm trying to make a card game where one of the moves a player can take is a swap option, wherein it takes the card in play (the element at index0 of an ArrayList) and swaps it with another. The index of that other card is found through a private method calling a method from a different class that computes for the health*power of that card (and labeled as determiningPower). The card found with the highest determiningPower is swapped with the card at index0.

So far what I wrote has errors because the methods are not of the same type. What can I do for this to work?

```
public java.lang.String swap()
{
    if (playerHand.size()>1) //playerHand is the ArrayList<Card> here
    {
        return "-1"; //if the hand only has one card, it cannot swap with anything and must return -1
    }
    else
    {
        Card temp = playerHand.get(0); //card is an object
        playerHand.set(0,playerHand.get(findCard())); //this is where the error is
        playerHand.set(findCard(),temp); //error also here
    }
}
```

This is the private method findCard() that is referenced in the method swap().

```
private java.lang.String findCard() //a method of swap that searches for the index number of the element in the array with the highest value
{
    int largest = 0;
    for (int i=1; i<playerHand.size(); i++)
    {
        if (playerHand.get(i).determiningPower()>playerHand.get(largest).determiningPower())
        {
            largest = i; //determiningPower is a method in a separate class that calculates the health*power. this should find which card has the highest determiningPower
        }
    }
    return java.lang.String.valueOf(largest); 
}
```

I'm pretty new to this, so any sort of help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your if statement is wrong. It is checking if there are elements in the list and you want to check if there are no elements. so  change  
`if(playerhand.size() >  1)` to `playerhand.size()<1`

Comment: @Harsh thanks for pointing that out! although the error is really coming from the else statement, specifically for **.get** and **.set**. it says there is "no suitable method found"

Comment: I think method `findCard` must return `int` but `String` value

Comment: @YuJiaao I replaced `private java.lang.String findCard()` with `private int findCard()` and it worked. thanks for your help!